# JAVA installed on Mac but not working

Tags: java, macos

I have had this issue for some time now. First of all, a window regularly pops up that tells me I have to have Java installed and leads me to the Java website where I can install it. I have installed it multiple times. It shows up in my System Preferences and everything. But when I run java -v it tells me there is no run time present!

I need Java in order to complete a coding challenge for a potential job. Really need help figuring out why Java is not being detected, and what keeps making the Java window pop up.

Comment: You can download JDK 8 from Oracle, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html ; The correct command for showing Java version is `java -version` ; Normally, the JDK is installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`, take a look whether any version has installed in this path.

Answer (score 0):

check with java -version.
Please refer this - https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml